# replacing a unary functor with a boost::phoenix actor

Tags: c++, boost, functor, boost-phoenix

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ application where I would like to replace a unary functor with a boost::phoenix lambda expression.

In my case, I have list of objects with containing a string. I want to remove all objects with a string that does not match the specified one. So, I use an algorithm like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    std::string my_type;
};

struct NotMatchType
{
    NotMatchType( const std::string& t ) : t_( t ) { };
    bool operator()( const Foo& f ) const
    {
        return f.my_type.compare( t_ ) != 0;
    };
    std::string t_;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector< Foo > list_of_foo;

    /*populate with objects*/

    std::string some_type = "some type";

    list_of_foo.erase(
        std::remove_if( list_of_foo.begin(),
                        list_of_foo.end(),
                        NotMatchType( some_type ) ),
        list_of_foo.end() );

    return 0;
}
```

This works fine. But, I'd like to clean up my code a bit and get rid of the `NotMatchType` functor and replace it with a simple lambda expression like this:

```
using boost::phoenix::arg_names::arg1;

list_of_foo.erase(
    std::remove_if( list_of_foo.begin(),
                    list_of_foo.end(),
                    arg1.my_type.compare( some_type ) != 0 ),
    list_of_foo.end() );
```

obviously, this doesn't work.

I have also tried: `( arg1->*&Foo::my_type ).compare( some_type ) != 0`

What do I need to do to make the boost:phoenix:actor look like a `Foo` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given two strings `lhs` and `rhs`, then `lhs == rhs` is specified to be semantically equivalent to `lhs.compare(rhs) == 0`. In other words, what your functor is doing is equivalent to doing `f.my_type != t_`.

With that in mind, you can express what you want with Phoenix as:

```
bind(&Foo::my_type, arg1) =! ref(some_type)
```

For the record, you were calling a member `compare` on a Phoenix actor. Since that member belongs to `std::string` though, that's not what you want. I can get the following to work:

```
typedef int (std::string::*compare_type)(std::string const&) const;
compare_type compare = &std::string::compare;
bind(compare, bind(&Foo::my_type, arg1), "") != 0;
```

where that last line is the final functor. But that's not good because there is no reliable way to get the address of an overloaded member of a Standard type. In other words the second line in the above is not guaranteed to compile.

For future reference I prefer lambdas when calling an overloaded member:

```
auto compare = [](std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs)
{ return lhs.compare(rhs); };
// bind that functor and use it as a Phoenix actor etc
```

Comment: `arg1` does not represent a pointer type, so using `operator->*` on it is ill-formed. `(&arg1)->*&Foo::my_type != ref(some_type)` should work.

Comment: lambdas (being part of c++11) are, tragically, not available on Visual Studio 2008

Comment: @ildjarn I do not follow. `operator->*` is overloaded; the code that I've shown compile on my end.

Comment: @Luc : From [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/operator.html#phoenix.modules.operator.member_pointer_operator): "*The left hand side of the member pointer operator must be an actor returning a pointer type.*" In this case, the left hand size (`arg1`) returns a reference type, not a pointer type.

Comment: @Luc Danton - @ildjarn is correct. Though the application will compile, I start getting errors. `Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'that' was corrupted.` in boost/proto/generate.hpp(223)

Comment: Replaced all instances of `->*` with `bind`. `(&arg1)->*&T::member` also is a possibility but too syntactically noisy for my taste.

Answer (score 4):

Using `std::string::compare()` directly from Phoenix is pretty ugly, since it's overloaded and we need to take its address:

```
phx::bind(
    static_cast<int (std::string::*)(std::string const&) const>(
        &std::string::compare
    ),
    phx::cref(some_type),
    phx::bind(&Foo::my_type, arg1)
) != 0
```

However, if we follow Luc's hint and simply compare object equality, it becomes more manageable:

```
phx::cref(some_type) != phx::bind(&Foo::my_type, arg1)
```

Comment: Is that any different than using boost::bind? `boost::bind( &Foo::my_type, _1 ) != boost::cref( some_type )`? Also, is the usage of `cref` necessary to keep it from performing a copy?

Comment: @PaulH : Yes, `boost::bind` would work in this context, but `std::bind` and `std::tr1::bind` would not. Yes, a copy will be made if `ref` or `cref` is not used.